# Trouble programming JInput for game controller

Tags: java, lwjgl, controllers

Due to lack of reasonable documentation, I have not been able to program inputs for using a game controller. The most I have ever found was how to detect if a controller is found and what it's name is. Does anyone know of a reliable tutorial on how to program controller buttons to perform any actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this Video will help you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIdmpaWf9Eo .

Comment: It helped a little bit, but I found a near complete example from this book: Pro Java 6 3D Game Development: Java 3D, JOGL, JInput and JOAL APIs. It had everything but how to program the right analog stick